# Как спроектировать бд для чатов?

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Имеется простейший чат на двоих человек. чатов на 2 может быть сколько угодно(Петя-Вася, Маша-Женя, и т.д).Для каждого чата отдельную таблицу? Или все чаты в одной таблице хранить? 
Если вдруг кто работал с requery ORM подскажите как это реализовать на этой бд?
Или лучше для чатов использовать другую бд на android?

Comment: В одной таблице.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82+%5Bsql%5D

Comment: спс, завтра буду пробовать, если что тут задам вопрос по бд

Answer (score 2):

Для начала вам надо определиться с архитектурой базы данных. Как минимум здесь потребуются 2 таблицы chats и messages. В первой хранятся данные для чатов (chat_id, uid собеседников), а во второй собственно сообщения, которые привязываются к chat_id, чтобы их не искать по комбинации uid, а выводить просто по id чата.

Но это самая простая архитектура, в современных чатах есть еще как минимум одна таблица, назовем ее peers (собеседники). Где хранится информация о людях, которые участвуют в переписке в конкретном чате (особенно актуально, когда в чате больше 2-х человек). Там обычно хранятся статусы (прочитан ли, удален ли этот чат у собеседника, кто отправил последнее сообщение), сниппеты (краткие заголовки чата, которые обычно выводятся в списке чатов берутся не из таблицы messages, а из peers), черновики сообщений и туда же пишутся ссылки на прикрепленные, но еще не отправленные в чат изображения/медиаданные.